# How do I execute a JQuery function on page load, but only once per unique user?

Tags: jquery, forms, popup, newsletter

I'm interested in creating a popup block with a newsletter form on my website. I'd want it to popup after I user is on the website for a certain duration. If the user submits the form or closes the block, I don't want the box to popup again, the next time they visit the site. I assume that you'd use cookies for some of the logic, but I honestly don't know where to begin. Is this difficult to implement, if not, how JQuery logic should I wrap my popup function in?

Answer (score 0):

Track the user by [setting a cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript)?